# How to use msiexec to update a program

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, auto-update

I have a .msi to install a program.  Upon 'update', I want to be able to check whether there is an update available on a server, and if there is, install it.

- Can msiexec do that?  I've looked around, and all I can find is that the /update just applies .msp patches.
- Is the .msp patch a patch for the installer itself, or for the installed application?
- Can the latest .msp patch different versions of an installer/installation to the latest one?

If this isn't possible through msiexec or this method is problematic, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Note: I have gone through the other auto-update posts on stackoverflow.  I was wondering if this could be done without maintaining a database or server page that tracks version number -- all those methods seem over-complex if msiexec can do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msiexec doesn't do anything like what you've described.

The msp file is a patch for the installed application, not the Installer service.

You can create a patch that is applicable to multiple products.  You define this behavior in the patch's summary information stream.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to check out [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) deployment.